# Retrofit "java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line", Anyone?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

My Android app crashed with the following stack trace, but when I try it from a desktop rest client it works well. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://beta2.irealtor.api.iproperty.com.my/Listing?pageSize=10000&orderby=1&order=-1
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ If-Modified-Since: 1398235278243
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ User-Agent: Android/0.0.20
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ Accept: application/json
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ Authorization: WFdSeW8vOTJ1Z3BoQlBJMk53VGpaekZRY2pCd1pYSlVXUT090
04-23 16:00:50.449  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
04-23 16:00:50.549  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ ---- ERROR http://beta2.irealtor.api.iproperty.com.my/Listing?pageSize=10000&orderby=1&order=-1
04-23 16:00:50.549  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: {"Data":[],"CustomStatusCode":200,"Status":"success"}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.<init>(StatusLine.java:38)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:150)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:99)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:595)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:381)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:328)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:493)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:71)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:358)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:284)
            at $Proxy0.syncProperties(Native Method)
            at com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor.sync.SyncHelper.performSync(SyncHelper.java:210)
            at com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor.sync.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:82)
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
04-23 16:00:50.549  27917-27983/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor D/Ireal_IrealtorClient﹕ ---- END ERROR


/**Sample code by using BasicHttpClient*/
BasicHttpClient httpClientTest = new BasicHttpClient();
httpClientTest.addHeader("If-Modified-Since", "1398312582192");
httpClientTest.addHeader("Authorization", "WFdSeW8vOTJ1Z3BoQlBJMk53VGpaekZRY2pCd1pYSlVXUT090");
httpClientTest.addHeader("User-Agent", "Android/0.0.20");
httpClientTest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

HttpResponse responseTest = httpClientTest.get("http://beta2.irealtor.api.iproperty.com.my/Listing?pageSize=100&orderby=1&order=-1",null);
final int statusTest = responseTest.getStatus(); // here i get 204, because i make server return 204 then there is nothing.
String body responseTest.getAsString() // here i get empty which is correct.
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You are missing authentication on your request.

Comment: i have passed in, have a look StackTrace line 4. @AlexvandenHoogen

Comment: Match your desktop client's web request with android app's web request and verify if they are same.

Comment: Yes I did it with desktop client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is causing problems with the response body length of the preceding HTTP request, and that's causing the pooled connection to become corrupted.

The preceding request was interpreted by OkHttp to have no body, but it has this body:

```
{"Data":[],"CustomStatusCode":200,"Status":"success"}
```

It's probably either a bug in the server, or a bug in OkHttp, depending on which headers and code was sent by the preceding URL. If you can paste the request that precedes this failure, we can figure out whose fault it is!

Comment: Will it be possible cause the response cache? now the endpoint manual set the httpstatus to 204 when the Data[] length is 0.

Comment: Disable the response cache and attempt to reproduce it! My guess is that it's the connection pool.

Comment: Connection pool? i disable the cache by using okHttpClient.setResponseCache(null);
okHttpClient.setOkResponseCache(null);

Comment: Ya...right now the api using .net servicestack...do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hi @Jesse Wilson, I have found the problem, that because servicestack v3.9.70 maybe different with standard or maybe some bug. Because the time concern. We remove the servicestack handle in web.config. now works perfectly when changed to .Net WepApi2. Thank you so much

Comment: Just sharing this to help if anyone makes the same mistake I did.

I had this PHP response on the server.

header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
echo "no-changes";
exit();

As Jesse explained, the echo after 304 corrupted next HTTP request.

Answer (score 28):

i add a network interceptor and add the close connection header to it for the okhttp3 client.

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Connection", "close").build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

And that solve the problem.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Making this change worked, whereas adding `@Headers("Connection:close")` to only the Retrofit method that was failing didn't.

Answer (score 14):

Also getting this response error when sending two POST requests in quick succession. The solution is to add header "Connection: close" for both of these requests.

Comment: If you have multiple requests, it's more reliable to add an interceptor as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36493143/369722.  Because you may be unable to control the timing of requests.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? My expertise is more on the client side of things.

Answer (score 11):

You can fix this by setting the header value `@Headers("Connection:close")` on your retrofit method.
This worked for me.